# Getting control back to a procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a procedure that calls an ETL. Is there any way I can get the control back to the procedure once the ETL finishes its run? Also is there any way I can get the control to the procedure in between the ETL runs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suggest to create a job.
and do something like this

```
X   Step   Procedure
X+1 Step   SSIS
X+2 Step   Next things.
```

because you can exec a job by sql, and you can controll all steps.

another solution i think is to exec a bat file with the SSIS exec command in it.

another solution is to use "traffic light" the store exec ETL and after wait the SSIS (the SSIS before Finish, set the Flag on a table)